# Proving the compactness of a subset of a compact set

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness

I have to prove the fact that, given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a subset $K$ of $X$ compact, taking a closed subset $C$ of $K$, this $C$ is compact too.

I have used the characterization of closed sets with sequences, stating that there exist a generic sequence $Xn$ in $C$ that converges to an $x$ belonging to the same set $C$.

Then, using the fact that, since a sequence converges, every subsequence converges to the same limit, I stated that, under the Bolzano-Weierstrass property, set $C$ is compact since a generic sequence of its has a convergent subsequence to a some point of the set.

Now my question is: is that reasoning correct? Since in the solution of the question, the professor uses the fact that $K$ is compact to state the existence of a subsequence that converges.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? That every sequence in C has a convergent subsequence? (Note: the proof that C is also compact may be easier using the open cover equivalence ;) )

Comment: I found a result that states that every convergent sequence in a set has convergent subsequences and then I tried to apply the Bolzano-Weierstrass property to check for compactness.

Comment: I'll just note that this has nothing to do with metric spaces: a closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct.  Every sequence in $C$ has a convergent subsequence because $K$ is compact.  However, the subsequential limit is in $K$.  You need to show that every subsequential limit is in $C$.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $C$.  Because, $K$ is compact, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ which converges to a point in $K$. Let $x=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}$.  So, $x\in\overline C$.  But $C$ is closed, therefore $x\in C$.

Comment: Ok that's clear. But does this mean that it is not true that every convergent sequence has convergent subsequences?

Comment: Yes, that is true, but to show that $C$ is compact, you need to show that every sequence in $C$, convergent or not, has a subsequence which converges in $C$.

Comment: Ok, so just keeping the convergent ones, I am excluding the non convergent; it is not like taking a generic one, is it too specific?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.